# How to get a list of pools containing a given token in Uniswap v3 and create a filtered list?

Tags: uniswap, arrays

Through the subgraph, preferably, is there a way to get a list of pools with only one token symbol provided?

My workaround so far is a bit tedious:
Get id for a given token
Perform an OR search in Pools, if the token ID is token0 or token1 - store these in an array

My next step is to search matching pools in say Sushiswap or another exchange then store any matching pools in a separate array/collection.

So my first question is if there is a better way to find matching v3 pools?

Secondly, looking for suggestions on creating a matched filtered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Uniswap v3 subgraph:

```
{
    tokens(where:{symbol:"DAI"}) {
    name
    id
    whitelistPools {
      id
      token0 {
        id
        symbol
      }
      token1 {
        id
        symbol
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The key here, is `whitelistPools`:

```
{
  "data": {
    "tokens": [
      {
        "id": "0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f",
        "name": "Dai Stablecoin",
        "whitelistPools": [
          {
            "id": "0x063332bbf9f8385e4106919b5c6ae2e6a4f72228",
            "token0": {
              "id": "0x111111111117dc0aa78b770fa6a738034120c302",
              "symbol": "1INCH"
            },
            "token1": {
              "id": "0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f",
              "symbol": "DAI"
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "0x091c0158ab410bd73ca1541409d5a22e90146a04",
            "token0": {
              "id": "0x514910771af9ca656af840dff83e8264ecf986ca",
              "symbol": "LINK"
            },
            "token1": {
              "id": "0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f",
              "symbol": "DAI"
            }
          },...
```

I am disappointed that that asking this on the [Uniswap #dev-chat Discord channel](https://discord.com/channels/597638925346930701/607978109089611786) rendered no responses.